# How to change the x-coordinate in stripchart?

Tags: r, stripchart

In the former question,Ananda Mahto  tell  me how to create a striochart ,
it is better to change the  x-coordinate  from 0,2,4,6,8,10 (in graph1) into    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 (in graph2)
How to change it ?

```
set.seed(1)
A <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
stripchart(A, method = "stack", offset = .5, at = .15, pch = 19, 
       main = "Dotplot of Random Values", xlab = "Random Values")
```

What i want is graph2.png not graph1.png.

The graph1.png

[image]

The graph2.png

[image]

Comment: Please read some basic introduction to R base graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A <- sample(0:9, 100, replace = TRUE)
stripchart(A, method = "stack", offset = .5, at = .15, pch = 19, 
           main = "Dotplot of Random Values", xlab = "Random Values",xaxt="n")
axis(1, at = 0:9, labels = 0:9)
```